# Precise Keyframing in Final Cut Pro X

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, animation

I'm wondering how I can expand the transformation line like it's possible for the compositing. Can it be done? Where can I edit the connection between two keyframes from linear to ...?

[image: Video animation dialoge: How to open the transformation pane like the compositing one at the bottom?]

Comment: Try clicking on the little triangle next to the name.  I don't have FCPX myself, but that generally indicates that something can be expanded.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expand the Transform Line in the Timeline. You can finetune your *Position* keyframes separately in the Viewer.

- Create keyframes and navigate between them with the keyframe buttons in the top-left corner of the Viewer.

  [image: keyframe buttons]

### Position keyframes

- Click the Transform button in the lower-left corner of the Viewer (Shift-T).

  [image: transform button]
- The yellow handles in the middle of your clip are your position keyframes. Control-click on one of them.

  [image: keyframe popup]
- Choose Smooth in the popup, you will see two smaller red dots, they are the bezier handles!

  [image: bezier handles]
- You can change direction and speed by moving the bezier handles.

  - change the length of the handle that points to the other keyframe
  - short means fast, long means slow
  - set your start speed in the first keyframe, and your end speed in the last keyframe.
  - if you make them both short, you will start gradually, speed up in the middle and slow down before stopping. use it for a smooth motion
  - if you make them both long, you will start promptly, slow down in the middle and stop abruptly. Use this effect to imitate gravity (bouncing)

### Rotation and Scale keyframes

- These can also be set separately but they are not visible on the Position line in the viewer as yellow dots.
- In the middle of your clip is the blue Rotation handle.
- On the corners and borders are the eight blue handles for Scaling.
- Scale and Rotation keyframes don't have a smooth option in FCPX. It might be possible to do that in Motion.